# What does the ICU License state about third party rights?

Tags: license

The license [link](https://github.com/hercules-390/decNumber-icu-368/blob/master/ICU-license.html). Can someone elaborate "NONINFRINGEMENT
OF THIRD PARTY RIGHTS"? What is being implied here? It's confusing to me. I will choose the answer with most votes.

Answer (score 6):

As I read it, it means that if your use of IBM's software causes somebody else to sue you for infringing their rights (whether copyright, patent rights, trademark rights, or, I suppose, the right to pass unimpeded upon the highway) IBM have in no way warranted that this will not come to pass.  Had IBM given you such a warranty, and had some third-party then successfully sued you, you would have reasonable grounds for a suit against IBM, to recover at least some of your costs.

The licence reads very much like the [MIT licence](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT); I rather suspect the ICU came out of passing MIT through IBM's legal department, who have tightened up some of the language a little.  Both ICU and MIT licences disclaim *all* warranties; but in the non-exhaustive list of such warranties that follows, MIT disclaims all warranties of non-infringement, which is a broader disclaimer than ICU's (a mere warranty of non-infringement of third-party rights).  So if MIT's warranty disclaimer is valid (and I have no reason to think it not so) then so is ICU's.

Comment: When can that happen? Say(logically) someone can only sue me(because of me using IBM code) if the IBM code already does that. Otherwise who can blame IBM, just because I had infringed another party's right. Isn't it redundant. Sake of clarity perhaps.

Comment: @SomOneElse read the second half of my first paragraph.  It's *you* suing IBM that IBM's worrying about in that particular clause.